# Logits representation in TensorFlow’s sparse_softmax_cross_entropy

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder, cross-entropy

I’ve a question regarding to the `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` cost function in TensorFlow.

I want to use it in a semantic segmentation context where I use an autoencoder architecture which uses typical convolution operations to downsample images to create a feature vector. This vector is than upsampled (using `conv2d_transpose`and one-by-one convolutions to create an output image.
Hence, my input consists of single channel images with shape `(1,128,128,1)`, where the first index represents the batch size and the last one the number of channels. The pixel of the image are currently either `0` or `1`. So each pixel is mapped to a class. The output image of the autoencoder follows the same rules. Hence, I can’t use any predefined cost function than either `MSE` or the previously mentioned one.

The network works fine with `MSE`. But I can’t get it working with `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`. It seems like that this is the correct cost function in this context but I’m a bit confused about the representation of the `logits`. The official doc says that the logits should have the shape `(d_i,...,d_n,num_classes)`. I tried to ignore the `num_classes` part but this causes an error which says that only the interval `[0,1)` is allowed. Of course, I need to specify the number of classes which would turn the allowed interval to `[0,2)` because the exclusive upper bound is obviously `num_classes`.

Could someone please explain how to turn my output image into the required logits?

The current code for the cost function is:

```
self._loss_op = tf.reduce_mean((tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.squeeze(self._target_placeholder, [3]), logits=self._model, name="Loss")))
```

The squeeze removes the last dimension of the label input to create a shape for the labels of `[1 128 128]`. This causes the following exception:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).
```

**Edit:**

As requested, here's a minimal example to verfiy the behavior of the cost function in the context of fully-convolutional nets:

`constructor` snipped:

```
def __init__(self, img_channels=1, img_width=128, img_height=128):
    ...
    self._loss_op = None
    self._learning_rate_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], 'lr')
    self._input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, img_width, img_height, img_channels], 'x')
    self._target_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, img_width, img_height, img_channels], 'y')
    self._model = self.build_model()
    self.init_optimizer()
```

`build_model()` snipped:

```
 def build_model(self):
        with tf.variable_scope('conv1', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            #not necessary
            x = tf.reshape(self._input_placeholder, [-1, self._img_width, self._img_height, self._img_channels])
            conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            conv1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, 2, 2)

        with tf.variable_scope('conv2', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 64, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            conv2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, 2, 2)
        with tf.variable_scope('conv3_red', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, 1024, 30, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        with tf.variable_scope('conv4_red', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv3, 64, 1, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        with tf.variable_scope('conv5_up', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            conv5 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv4, 32, (128, 128), strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        with tf.variable_scope('conv6_1x1', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            conv6 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv5, 1, 1, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        return conv6
```

`init_optimizer()` snipped:

```
def init_optimizer(self):
    self._loss_op = tf.reduce_mean((tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.squeeze(self._target_placeholder, [3]), logits=self._model, name="Loss")))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self._learning_rate_placeholder)
    self._train_op = optimizer.minimize(self._loss_op)
```

Answer (score 1):

[By definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41455101/712995) the logit is an *unscaled probability* (strictly speaking *odds*) or simply put *any* number. The sequence of logits of length `num_classes` can be interpreted as unscaled probability distribution. For example, in your case, `num_classes=2`, then `logits=[125.0, -10.0]` is an unscaled probability distribution for one pixel (which clearly favors `0` over `1`). This array can be squashed to a valid distribution by a [softmax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965817/712995), and this is what `tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` does internally. For `[125.0, -10.0]` the squashed distribution will be very close to `[1.0, 0.0]`.

Once again, the array `[2]` is for a *single* pixel.
If you want to compute the cross-entropy over entire image, the network has to output the binary distribution for all pixels and all images in a batch, i.e. output `[batch_size, 128, 128, 2]` tensor. The term *sparse* in the name of the loss refers to the fact that the *labels* are not one-hot encoded (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995)). It's most useful when the number of classes is large, i.e. one-hot encoding becomes too inefficient in terms of memory, but in your case it's insignificant. If you decide to use `tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` loss, the labels must be `[batch_size, 128, 128]`, it must be `tf.int32` or `tf.int64` and must contain correct class indices, zero or one. That's it: tensorflow can compute the cross-entropy between these two arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. When I use the suggested shape, I get the following error:

 Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values:...

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: By the way, you reached your 666 answer which matches your profile pic quite well. I'd leave it this way ;)

Comment: @BastianSchoettle Did you check the labels? Note that they must be binary

Comment: @BastianSchoettle Looks like I also need 666 questions to make it perfect.

Comment: Yes defintily, the labels are binary thats why it complains about the 1s in [0,1). It's an exclusive upper boundary intervall. Here its a small subset of the pixels/labels:  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Start asking fancy things then :)

Comment: @BastianSchoettle Oops, one minor correction. The labels shape should be `[?, 128, 128]`, and it must be `tf.int32`. This way tf is not complaining for me.

Comment: It still causes the same error. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you make a short example to reproduce it? The code I tried worked.

Comment: Sure! I’ll post it tomorrow and thank you very much for your help

Comment: I’ve added the example to my question

Comment: @Bastian , I had the same problem, I think the problem is the input to sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits: If you have two classes, the input needs to have shape  (batch_size, 2) . One output per class, = 2. (You can probably concatenate your output with a vector of ones, and feed that into the function.)

Comment: In your case, you have                                                                       conv6 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv5, 1, 1, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu), so probably an output of size 1?

Comment: That was the solution! Did missunderstood the concept in general, Thanks a lot!